# How to embed Plotly graphs in Sphinx documentation and nbsphinx

Tags: python, plot, jupyter-notebook, plotly, python-sphinx

I tried using *nbsphinx* to embed a Jupyter notebook containing plotly plots, but the plots don't show up in the documentation, even though they look fine on the Jupyter notebook.

How can I embed a plotly graph in **Sphinx** [documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/contents.html)? I could include them as images, but is there a better way? It'd be nice to have the interactivity!

What I want to do is replicate [this page](https://plot.ly/python/ipython-notebook-tutorial). It has Jupyter notebook style in and out blocks, and it shows interactive plots made using plotly. How can I do that?

GitHub issue raised [here.](https://github.com/spatialaudio/nbsphinx/issues/128)

Comment: Same problem here. There exists https://github.com/plotly/plotlyhtmlexporter. Not sure how one could utilize it from nbsphinx. Also it messes up other HTML cells in my notebooks.

Comment: @phantomas1234 I've updated the question with a link to the GitHub issue I raised. Try the solution on there and see if it works for you.

Comment: With plotly you can output html with `output_type='div'`.

Comment: This is easier with the new `FigureWidget`. I can prepare an answer if there's interest.

Answer (score 3):

I can see two solutions to embed your notebook cells with plotly figures in a sphinx documentation.

1. Convert the notebook to html using nbconvert or nbsphinx. Be sure to use the `notebook` renderer in order to include the plotly javascript bundle (maybe this was the reason why your figures did not display): see https://plot.ly/python/renderers/ for the documentation on plotly renderers. Then you can include the html in your sphinx doc with various solutions (see [Include standalone HTML page in sphinx document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48889270/include-standalone-html-page-in-sphinx-document)).
2. Use sphinx-gallery (https://sphinx-gallery.github.io/) with its plotly scraper. With sphinx-gallery you write your doc page as a python script which is converted to rest by the sphinx-gallery extension of sphinx. In order to configure the scraper see https://sphinx-gallery.github.io/advanced.html#integrate-custom-scrapers-with-sphinx-gallery. We have also a minimal repository showing how to use plotly and sphinx-gallery together in https://github.com/plotly/plotly-sphinx-gallery.
   https://github.com/plotly/plotly-sphinx-gallery

Answer (score 3):

The graph itself is an HTML inside jupyter notebook file.
You can open notebook.ipnb file in any text editor, find where HTML of the graph starts,  copy all this html into html file ans save it , say a.html, and then just insert raw html in RST doc.

```
.. raw:: 
    :file: a.html
```

Answer (score 2):

We had this issue for both `sphinx_rtd_theme` and `furo` theme. Because how Plotly and Sphinx themes using `require.js`, the default generated HTML output does not work within Sphinx context. You get various loading errors with require.js or other files.

Here is our solution:

- Make sure your JavaScript loads at `<head>` in your theme. If it loads at the end of the `<body>` no workaround is going to work.
- Server `require.js` locally from Sphinx `_static` folder
- Configure `require` by using custom.js

Example `conf.py`:

```py
html_js_files = [
    "require.min.js",  # Add to your _static
    "custom.js",
]
```

Example custom.js:

```js
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        base: '/static/base',
        plotly: 'https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.12.1.min.js?noext',
    },
});
```

This way

- Notebook correctly renders interactive diagrams when running in Jupyter
- Notebook correctly renders interactive diagrams when viewed as static HTML files
- Notebook correctly renders interactive diagrams when viewed on ReadTheDocs

[See the example open-source documentation here](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/) and [the example notebook](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/tutorials/uniswap-v3-price-analysis.html).

Answer (score 1):

After trying many workarounds, the solution that worked for me was to add these lines at the beginning of the notebook.

```html
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
```

None of the solutions involving modifying the options `nbsphinx_prolog`, `nbsphinx_requirejs_options` and `html_js_files` in the `conf.py`, work for me.

I'm ussing the `sphinx_rtd_theme` html theme and the following versions:

```
nbsphinx==0.8.9
sphinx-autobuild==2021.3.14
sphinx==4.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

From Python, you can generate the HTML code to embed Plotly graphs with the plotly.tools.get_embed function.

```
import plotly.tools as tls

tls.get_embed('https://plot.ly/~chris/1638')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Jupyter Sphinx Extension](https://jupyter-sphinx.readthedocs.io/):

```
.. jupyter-execute::

   import plotly.graph_objects as go

   trace = go.Scatter(
       x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16],
   )
   layout = go.Layout(title='Growth')
   figure = go.Figure(data=[trace], layout=layout)
   figure.show()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with my pdflatex...is there some jupyter-execute setup you have earlier in the document?

Comment: @MattRuge I have not tried with LaTeX output, so I don't know. :-)

Comment: I made some progress by having the jupyter-execute dump the IMG bytes, shows up as a png in the latex pdf
```
    .. jupyter-execute::
        :hide-code:
    # Creates figure ## REDACTED FOR BREVITY

    img_bytes = fig.to_image(format="png")
    Image(img_bytes)
```

Comment: I believe plotly won't generate a static plot by default unless you configure it explicitly with https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/. I am currently looking to have a README.rst file with an interactive plotly graph in a Github repository, so far I have managed to with static image.

Answer (score 0):

When Sphinx generate the document it doesn't describe the plotly library, so  add the following line into your HTML page:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
```

then the page will be alive again.

Answer (score -1):

Try this at the top of your notebook:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "sphinx_gallery"
```

This renderer makes sure your notebook (or cell output, or something, not sure!) includes the javascript resources that your cell output needs to render the plot.

Other renderers, or settings, might achieve this as well. But so far this is the only renderer I've tried where I can build notebooks with sphinx (jupyter book, actually), and the interactive plots show up in the build.