# Include standalone HTML page in sphinx document

Tags: html, python-sphinx

For most of my project's documentation I prefer a standard sphinx layout.  However for the landing page I would prefer to use custom HTML/CSS/JS without any of the layout, TOC, or sidebars of the normal sphinx site.  Is there a way to include a raw HTML standalone page in a sphinx-generated website in a way that completely disregards the normal layout of the rest of the site?

As a counter example I know that I can include raw HTML bits into a page using the following (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46960524/how-to-include-raw-html-file))

```
.. raw:: html
   :file: myfile-html
```

However this just embeds a file within the normal layout.  I would like to have a completely standalone HTML page.

Comment: You can change the base `index` page to something else in `conf.py` (the `master_doc` setting), and manually include your own raw `index.html` file in build.

Comment: To clarify a bit, you can include raw html pages in the output with the `html_extra_path` setting in `conf.py` http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/config.html#confval-html_extra_path. In your case you'd change `master_doc='docs'` (or a different path) to not generate an `index.html` page, and add `html_extra_path=['index.html']` to include your raw landing page file.

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into this problem myself, and the way I solved it was to simply include the html file in my `source/_static` folder, then refer to it with a relative link.

So if `source/_static/my_standalone.htm` is the path where I have my non-generated HTML file, and the .rst file where I want to type my link is at `source/otherfolder/index.rst`, I write it like this in my rst:

```
Link to my non-Sphinx HTML file
===============================

To get to my standalone, non-generated HTML file, 
just `click here <../_static/my_standalone.html>`_ now!
```